# In-App Purchase in new version of the App

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, app-store, in-app-purchase

I have a live app on the App Store, which is currently version 1.0 with 5 in-app.

I just created the version 1.1 in the iTunes Connect but I was not able to configure my in-apps for my new version. Will my existing in-apps assigned to my new version automatically or do I have to configure it ? And If so, how?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Existing In-App purchase will continue to work, you don't have to do anything special with that.

If you're introducing new In-App purchases you have to create these and put together with the update into review.

Comment: How older In App Purchase will continue to work because newer version will take over the older version. Where we can see the details of the older In App Purchase?

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't have to reassign the IAPs to your new vernon of App. You can modify IAPs in:

> Manage Your Applications -> YouApp -> Manage In-App Purchases

And make sure that all status are **Approved**. If not, submit it.